# Do CIP codes apply to only undergrads?

Tags: collegescorecard

The 2 digit CIP code data are in the form of fractions.  If I want to know how many graduates this translates to, do I multiply these fractions by the number of undergrad degrees or does it also include graduate degrees?  I believe CIP codes themselves don't distinguish between undergraduate and graduate degrees, so I can't tell if those fractions also apply to both.